# Mercurial will not recognize new folder in repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have an existing repo which has been setup correctly and working fine. I deleted an entire project folder from the repo, committed the change, then added another version of the same folder which was not under VC. Now when I try to add or commit files in the new folder, Mercurial does not seem to recognize any of the new files.

Using the TortoiseHg Windows Explorer "commit" extension, when I try to the commit the folder(or any of the files within), no files show up in the dialogue. If I right click and commit a file within the folder, a pop up comes up that says "No files found for this operation". I am no Hg expert, although I have been using it for few months without a hitch, but I am pretty stuck on this one. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I have added a screenshot below showing what happens when I try to add the new folder. None of the files in the folder seem to be recognized.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project I had copied had been a part of another repo, so it contained hg reference files. I deleted these, and everything added/committed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to commit a new file to a repository, you must first `add` it.

On the command line this can be done in various ways :

1. `hg add` which can add a file or a repository and every files it contains.
2. `hg addremove` which adds all new files and remove deleted ones.
3. `hg commit -A` or `hg commit --addremove` which are the same thing and a shortcut of `hg add remove; hg commit`.

I don't remember exactly where the command is in TortoiseHG, but I think if you right-click on the folder in the explorer, the option should be present.

I think I also remember an `addremove` option somewhere in the commit window, but I may be mistaken.

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the answer you provided yourself, here is the explanation of why simply adding the files weren't working :

Since the new directory contained repository related information (a `.hg` directory), Mercurial was treating it as a [Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository). Subrepositories are repository contained in another, this can, for example, be used to reference a specific version of a library.

Once you delete the `.hg` directory in your new location, Mercurial didn's saw this as a Subrepo anymore and you were able to add the files normally.

Comment: When I try to add, none of the files seem to be recognized from the project I copied into the repo. See my screen shot above. Does this clarify?

Comment: Also, I have tried all of the options above from the command line, but it still does not seem to recognize the files.